# Windows 8 and Desktop Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

I found out that windows 8 is going to be heavily dependent on C++, HTML5 and CSS based apps(WPF ?). I spend a lot of time working on applications like matlab, scipy and C# as programming language at my workplace. Considering this, is there going to be any big change for desktop app developers ? are these apps going to be re-written under new code and C# has any future for desktop apps?

Comment: Could you indicate the source of this information?

Comment: @jakub-Two sources : http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2011/06/html5-centric-windows-8-leaves-microsoft-developers-horrified.ars and http://www.redmountainsw.com/wordpress/archives/an-open-letter-to-silverlight-pms-at-microsoft

Comment: How are we supposed to know? We're not from Microsoft. And even the folks there won't tell you. Just wait for the PDC in september.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of hearsay at the moment until September it seems there is nothing definite.

> There is wide speculation on whether Jupiter will be the unifying
>   user-interface model for Windows, Web and mobile.  Burela believes
>   Jupiter may a “next generation” XAML-based framework, perhaps a
>   “mashup between WPF & Silverlight.”
>
> There also appears to be equally strong support for three key
>   programming languages:  C# to appease the .NET developers, C++ to
>   appease the Windows core developers, and HTML5/JavaScript to try to
>   lure developers from other platforms.
>
> Of course the controversy has been Microsoft’s focus on JavaScript
>   while nearly ignoring Silverlight and .NET developers.  Articles like
>   this one — though unofficial and speculative — should help calm some
>   nervous developers.

Source: http://www.isdotnetdead.com/windows-8-supports-all-programming-models/#

[ZDnet try asking probing questions](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/under-the-windows-8-hood-questions-and-answers-from-the-trenches/9738?tag=mantle_skin%3Bcontent).

[Here is another link about the future of C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisa/archive/2011/03/22/pdc10-future-directions-for-c-visual-basic-and-f.aspx)

Comment: Thanks this clears some of my confusion about C#'s future.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, your question confuses some terms - based on the articles you cite.

Microsoft are quoted as saying that the application they demonstrated on Windows 8 was written using HTML and JavaScript. The article interprets this as saying that WPF and Silverlight are likely to be binned in favour of HTML and JavaScript.

Let's have a think about this.

As far as I'm aware, Microsoft have been really keen to run applications in the Browser for a very long time. They have made ActiveX controls that run in a browser, they have written Silverlight to run in a browser. They are one of the leaders in the whole "browser based applications" concept. People may criticise their methods of achieving this in the past, but at least they were trying.

When you consider that Microsoft currently have a desktop package called Office and also a web-based package called Office365, you can understand why they might want to just have one package to maintain that works on the desktop and in a browser.

My final note - the ARS Technica article describes HTML tooling as inferior, but seeing as you can use the same tools to write a WPF application or an HTML application I don't agree with this point.